# Tomcat 7 session times out but postgres sql connection stays active

Tags: java, database, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

We utilize a vendor application that uses Tomcat 7 and Postgres DB. Our postgres instance has a limit of 300 connections and we are maxing out because when Tomcat expires the sessions after 30mins it doesn't kill the db connection. Unfortunately we don't have access to the source code only the war file.

We were utilizing a script that kills all idle connections that have no activity for 60mins but this was causing issues because Tomcat still thought there was a connection out there so items weren't displaying completely.

I was wondering if there is some type of configuration in Tomcat that maybe can kill these db connections being idle for a certain period of time? Any thoughts? Unfortunately the vendor has been researching the issue for months and haven't found a solution.

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how the application access the database.

If the application accesses the database directly by managing its own connection pool, then there's nothing that Tomcat can/will do to release abandoned connection.

If the application accesses the database through a connection pool that is managed by Tomcat, then the connection pool can be configured to get rid of abandoned connections:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

Proper application development calls for relying on the container for providing JDBC connections, so if your vendor designed their application well, then just configure the connection pool accordingly. However, as you were mentioning that your vendor has been researching this issue for months, it's quite possible that the application goes directly to the database; nothing (that I know of) can be done in that case to resolve the situation you get to with maxed connections.